# Whats wrong with my if else statement

Tags: boolean-logic

I have a `$name` variable containing a string, and when I test it, I never get the "Name should be between 2 and 40 characters" error even when it's less than 2 characters long or more than 40. Why?

```
if (strlen($name) < 2 && strlen($name) > 40) {
    $nameError = 'Name should be between 2 and 40 characters';
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think this one will be used for later questions ;-)

Answer (score 6):

How can the length be less than 2 **and** greater than 40? You want `||` ("or"), not `&&` ("and").

```
if (strlen($name) < 2 || strlen($name) > 40) {
// -------------------^^
```

Comment: Kind of like [*"You can't have your cake and it eat too"*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_can't_have_your_cake_and_eat_it)