# else condition is not working for src attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, src

Been trying add alt text in the web page using jquery below code however 
able to get correct value for the 1st image but else if and else conditions 
are not working properly. Not able to add alt texts for the other images

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("img ").each(function() {
    var img = $(this);

    if (!img.attr("alt") || img.attr("src") === "/temp/iconcache/flags/32x32/flag_brazil.png")
      img.attr("alt", "Brazil Flag");
    else if (!img.attr("alt") || img.attr("src") === "/temp/iconcache/flags/32x32/flag_China.png")
      img.attr("alt", "China Flag");
    else {
      img.attr("alt", "");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Sort of the converse of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190142/whats-wrong-with-my-if-else-statement.

Comment: Here you go: 
`$("img").each(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    if (!img.attr("alt") && img.attr("src") === "/temp/iconcache/flags/32x32/flag_brazil.png")
      img.attr("alt", "Brazil Flag");
    else if (!img.attr("alt") && img.attr("src") === "/temp/iconcache/flags/32x32/flag_China.png")
      img.attr("alt", "China Flag");
    else {
      img.attr("alt", "");
    }
});`

You can also use `indexOf` to check if src contains a text.
eg: `if(!img.attr("alt") && img.attr("src").indexOf("flag_brazil.png")  !== -1)`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `||` when you want `&&`. Each of your conditions has `if (!img.attr("alt") || ...` which means that if the image's `alt` attribute is null, the remainder of the conditional expression will be ignored. This means a null `alt` will cause the first branch ("brazil") to be run, regardless of the value of the `src` attribute.

Comment: You could also add an `if (!img.attr('alt')) return;` before the other ifs to short-circuit the rest of the code. That way you don't have to repeat that check.